# ObjectName of a button when clicked in PySide6

Tags: pyside

In PySide6, how to identify the objectName of a button when clicked?

I have a screen with several buttons and I need to identify the objectName of the clicked button.

Comment: Your [*identical* question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74763270/2001654) was closed as a duplicate. If you don't agree with the reason or don't understand its contents, then add a comment. Do ***not*** delete it just to reopen a new one that is identical to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all buttons connect to same slot, just use self.sender() to identify which button is clicked. Easy example as below, you can copy it and run for test, enjoy it~

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MyWidget_TestButton()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_A.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked_slot)
        self.ui.pushButton_B.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked_slot)

    def button_clicked_slot(self, clicked):
        # get clicked button and do anything you need.
        sender = self.sender()
        self.ui.label.setText(f"{sender.objectName()} is clicked ~")


class Ui_MyWidget_TestButton(object):
    def setupUi(self, MyWidget_TestButton):
        if not MyWidget_TestButton.objectName():
            MyWidget_TestButton.setObjectName(u"MyWidget_TestButton")
        MyWidget_TestButton.resize(369, 178)
        self.pushButton_A = QPushButton(MyWidget_TestButton)
        self.pushButton_A.setObjectName(u"pushButton_A")
        self.pushButton_A.setGeometry(QRect(80, 70, 75, 24))
        self.pushButton_B = QPushButton(MyWidget_TestButton)
        self.pushButton_B.setObjectName(u"pushButton_B")
        self.pushButton_B.setGeometry(QRect(210, 70, 75, 24))
        self.label = QLabel(MyWidget_TestButton)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(100, 130, 171, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(0, 85, 255);")

        self.retranslateUi(MyWidget_TestButton)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyWidget_TestButton)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MyWidget_TestButton):
        MyWidget_TestButton.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MyWidget_TestButton", u"TestButton", None))
        self.pushButton_A.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MyWidget_TestButton", u"Button_A", None))
        self.pushButton_B.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MyWidget_TestButton", u"Button_B", None))
        self.label.setText("")
    # retranslateUi


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: @JoséMariaAlexandreSilva if an answer helps you to solve your question, then you should click the grey tick mark on its left to *accept* it (please take your time to *carefully* follow the [tour]). That said, as previously pointed out, your question (and its previous attempt) was **already** answered, so please learn the rules of the website instead of attempting to override them.